# ERROR READING STRING

Tags: c, string, deque

My code does not work. I get run time error at the moment i accept a string. What is the problem with this code?

```
//this is what i have in main()
char *ele,*s[max];
int *count,temp=0;
count=&temp;   
printf("Enter string to insert: ");
scanf("%s",ele);
addleft(s,ele,count);

//following is the function definition
void addleft(char *s[max],char *ele,int *count)
{
    int i;
    if((*count)==max)
    {
        printf("Queue full!\n");
        return;
    }
    for(i=*count;i>0;i--)
        strcpy(s[i],s[i-1]);
    strcpy(s[0],ele);
    (*count)++;
    printf("String inserted at left!\n");
}
```

Comment: I would change the title to "Faulty code implementation leads to erroneous input string handling".  The title sounds like you are blaming the input string for the code being wrong.  ;-)

Comment: Sorry i din't pay attention to the title. what matters more to me at this time is the code as i got to submit this tom :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ele` is an uninitialised `char*` and has no memory associated with it and `scanf()` will be attempting to write to it causing undefined behaviour, a segmentation fault is probable.

You need to either dynamically allocate memory for `ele` or declare a local array and prevent buffer overrun when using `scanf()`:

```
char ele[1024];
if (1 == scanf("%1023s", ele))
{
    /* Process 'ele'. */
}
```

Additionally, the function `addleft()` is using `strcpy()` on `s`, which is an array of `char*` and each of the `char*` in the array is unitialised. This is undefined behaviour and a probable segmentation fault. To correct, you could use `strdup()` if it is available otherwise `malloc()` and `strcpy()`:

```
/* Instead of:
       strcpy(s[0],ele);
   use:
 */
s[0] = strdup(ele);
```

Note that the `for` loop inside the `addleft()` function is dangerous as the `char*` contained within `s` are not necessarily of the same length. This could easily lead to writing beyond the end of arrays. However, as the elements are addresses of dynamically allocated `char*` you can just swap the elements instead of copying their content.

Answer (score 0):

sscanf("%s", ele) is putting the input in the memory pointed to by 'ele'. But 'ele' has never been initialized to point to anything. Something like:

```
char ele[128];
```

or

```
char* ele = malloc(...)
```

should fix it up.

Answer (score -1):

You are causing a buffer overflow because the pointer `ele` is not pointing to any allocated memory. You are writing into memory that your program needs to run, therefore crashing it. I recommend you implement `malloc`into your program like this:

```
char *ele;
if (!(ele = malloc(50))) //allocate 50 bytes of memory 
{
    //allocation failed
    exit(0);
}
scanf("%s", ele); //string can hold 50 bytes now
free(ele);        //free allocated space
```

You might want to read up on the `malloc` function [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/malloc/)

An easier route would just to make `ele` an array instead of a pointer:

```
char ele[50]; //ele is an array of 50 bytes
```